# Process file on access in Linux

Tags: linux

Need help to process file on access in Linux.

For example PHP can be taken. It has plain text config at `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and can be customized by php `--php-ini=path`

php <- plain text config <- decrypter <- encrypted config

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite get your question, can you rephrase you problem?

Comment: @martin I think that he meant for example, you just save an encrypted copy of PHP configuration, and with `--php-ini=/etc/php5/cli/php.ini.encrypted`, the PHP can get a decrypted copy automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this Bash trick to replace filenames with commands, provided you are using Bash to run it:

```
php --php-ini=<(decrypter php.ini.encrypted)
```